# Adding elements when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

JavaScript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function createRow() {
        var d = document.createElement("section");
        d.className = "gallery-row";
        document.getElementById("gallery").appendChild(d);

    }

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <section id="container-main">
        <section id="gallery">
            <section class="gallery-row">
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
            </section>
            <section class="gallery-row">
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
            </section>
            <section class="gallery-row">
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
                <img src="../images/circles/myresume-a.png" alt="image" width="150px" height="150px" />
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="load-more"><button onclick="createRow();">Load More</button></section>
    </section>
```

The Problem:

Simply put, the script does not create a section element after the last element in the section with the ID "gallery" as intended. I've been struggling with this for hours and I'm not sure how to proceed. If someone could point out what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it. I've looked over documentation, but to no avail.

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want that the button always stays at the bottom?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me, but the section that is inserted has no content, so you won't really see it ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/4x9vcpw4/

Comment: I guess that goal is to 'clone' one section and append it: e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/4x9vcpw4/2/

Comment: @maraca Yes. I would like the button to remain at the bottom. My goal is to create a script that loads a new set of images below the current set every time the button is pushed.

Comment: @adeneo Strange. I keep looking at the page source on Safari to find the newly created element, but it isn't shown in the page source?

Comment: @user3277088, dynamically created elements are not visible in page source - inspect elements (not sure about Safari tool for this), and you will see...

Comment: @nevermind Ah, I see. I just used the inspect element tool and it has displayed.

Comment: @user3277088 if you only edited a bit the `section`'s css styles by adding some padding and a background color you'd see that (empty) element  appear in the page.

Answer (score 1):

What you have works fine, there's just nothing in the  so you don't see it.
Try this and you'll see it:

```
function createRow() {
    var d = document.createElement("section");
    d.className = "gallery-row";
    d.innerHTML = "test"
    document.getElementById("gallery").appendChild(d);

}
```